# Introduction to subfactor theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, banach-algebras, knot-theory, fusion-categories

I have almost no knowledge about subfactor theory but I would like to understand what it is. As a self-learner, I do not know where to start. Could you suggest introductory text/paper/book to study subfactor theory.

By a subfactor theory, I mean something related to planar algebra, fusion categories, knot invariant.

I have some basic knowledge about fusion categories but never studied planar algebra.

Comment: Your tags are strange, so I added what I thought was appropriate. From what I understand, subfactors are a part of the theory of Von Neumann algebras, which are related to $C^*$-algebras, both of which are special types of Banach algebras. These subjects can be found in advanced books on functional analysis and/or operator algebras, e.g. Kadison and Ringrose (although I have no idea whether this is a particularly good book; it's just the one on my bookshelf).

Comment: Your question would be much more suitable on mathoverflow with the tags planar-algebras ; subfactors ; qa.quantum-algebra ; oa.operator-algebras ; fusion-categories. In the meantime, have a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_algebra

Answer (score 1):

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9909027 is Planar Algebras I by Jones.